# how to import an image into openjscad

Tags: openscad, openjscad

I am trying to draw on an image that I have. 2D
the image is of a laptop and I want to draw lines around it to get measurements. I am very new to openjscad and am stuck on this very first step. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You might want to convert your Design to svg using a tool like inkscape.

Then you can import your design by drag & drop.
See

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenJSCAD_User_Guide#Supported_Language_/_File_Formats